# Automatic Captive Login Ubuntu 20.04 Using Ethernet

Tags: networking, scripts, login, firefox, ethernet

I'm using campus PC connected to the WiFi via Ethernet. Every 00:00, it reset all network connection. How to automate captive login every time it's not connected?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and Firefox Browser

The page for the captive login is not opened automatically and a website must be written, for example:

```
https://sso.campus_name.ac.id/cas/login?service=https...login
```

I've read [tutorial](https://peromsik.com/codearea/automate-captive-portal-login-ubuntu-linux-17-04/) for ubuntu 17.04, but that's for WiFi and previous version of ubuntu. Other [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/automated-login-for-captive-portals-in-linux/), but I can't understand the finding JavaScript part.

_

I'm going to use it for work/school from home.

So my questions are:

1. How to create a script that do the automatic login
2. How to send the new IP address (or any framework to set up the connection of remote desktop)*

*If using a framework or services, free for commercial use services is preferable (noip is not for commercial use).

Comment: Setting up a captive login is non-trivial.. However here is a link to some detailed instructions for setting up a captive portal. Though its for a Raspberry pi but the packages and instructions are 99% the same. https://gremaudpi.emf-informatique.ch/how-to-build-a-captive-web-portal-with-any-router-and-a-raspberry-pi/

Comment: @SimonBanks I've read the link, but seem unable to follow for my case. But thanks,